# How to plot all the matrix elements in matlab whitout knowing the size?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matrix, linear-algebra

Lets say there is the next matrix

```
A = [ 1 2 2 ;
      1 2 3 ;
      2 3 4 ;
      3 4 5 ;
      4 4 6 ;
      1 11 12]
```

I try to use quiver3 to plot the row in the next way:

```
quiver3(0,0,0,A(1:1),A(1:2),A(1:3),0);
quiver3(0,0,0,A(2:1),A(2:2),A(2:3),0);
quiver3(0,0,0,A(3:1),A(3:2),A(3:3),0);
```

and so on until  the last row, but how can apply quiver3 for each row of the matrix instead of making one line per row?
Besides, isn't the same size of matrix always, so making one one command per row would yield some rows without plotting sometimes and perhaps not enough rows to plot other .
(Example: the matrix provided has 6 rows so I make 6 quiver3 expressions, but later if the matrix has only 3 rows, it gives me an error and if later it has 8 rows, there would be 2 vectors/row that aren't plotted).
Im guessing that it has to do with the range and meshgrid operator but I can not see how.

Comment: The code you show is wrong, the indexing of `A` is not correct. I do not know what you expect this code to do, but its likely not doing it

Comment: What exactly is the desired output? A bunch of vectors from the origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your matrix `A` has `N` rows, where each row stores the `[u v w]` components to pass to [`quiver3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html), then you can plot all `N` arrows in one call to `quiver3`, provided you ensure all of your input arguments are the same size. If you are plotting all of them starting from the origin, then you have to create an `N`-by-1 vector of zeroes to use for your `x`, `y`, and `z` inputs:

```
A = [1 2 2;
     1 2 3;
     2 3 4;
     3 4 5;
     4 4 6;
     1 11 12];
z = zeros(size(A, 1), 1);
quiver3(z, z, z, A(:, 1), A(:, 2), A(:, 3), 0);
```

Note the [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html) syntax I used to split `A` up into columns to pass to `quiver3`. And here's the resulting plot for the given sample data:

[image]